# Dropdown menu inside a sliding menu

Tags: html, css

Im having a little bit of trouble trying to figure out a way to add a submenu, or a dropdown menu, inside one of the sections of my sliding menu
Also Im not sure how to do the adjustments for when the menu drops down, the other sections(text 2 and text 3) adjuste themselves to the screen.

Could anyone help me with this?
Appreciate the help!

[I'd like to have a dropdown menu coming out of "Text 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aFQR.png)

Comment: could you also present your code?

Comment: @AniketLodh I just realized, the edit queue is full, so no more edits are available, meaning he *can't* show the code...

Comment: yep noticed it  right  now!.. Uploaded an answer I have understood from the picture.. Hope  this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This accordion should be working.
I have tried to keep it as basic as possible to not make the code messy.
You can make this more beautiful and more user friendly by adding a icon to right side of the label ...For that im putting a link of my codepen [Here](https://codepen.io/aniket-lodh/pen/ZEoEvpO?editors=1100)

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #2c3e50;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:white;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #2c3e50;
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

input:checked+.tab-label {
  background: darken(#2c3e50, 10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="submenu_accordion">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chck1">
      <label class="tab-label" for="chck1">Item 1</label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum, reiciendis!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```